# Product order/purchase model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a product model with name, description, currency, price, vendor and image fields, and I'm trying to implement ordering items, and I'm having a bit of trouble doing that.

Basically, what I want is to be able to access an Orders model in the admin and add an order number, customer name (I have already implemented these two), and some products with each product having a quantity.

```py
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    currencies = [
    ('$', "US Dollars ($)"), 
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.TextField()
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=currencies, default="$")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default="not_found.jpg")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

### My attempts/solutions:

1. Adding ManyToManyField to Product (No Quantity)
2. Creating ProductInstance class with fk to product and order (Quantity added but You have to visit 2 different pages in the admin, and you can't see the items in orders page of admin)

Are there any other ways I can implement this or am I stuck with the second solution? It wouldn't be awful to do this but I rather avoid it and have the ability to add items on the orders page

*I'm sorry if I sound like a beggar. I'm really not but I can't form nice-sounding sentences*

### Edit: I found what I needed!

Using the second solution I mentioned, I created a class called ProductInstance, and later renamed it to OrderProduct, made the following fields:

1. ForeignKey to Products
2. ForeignKey to Orders
3. IntegerField for quantity

The `order` class had the following fields:

1. CharField for order number
2. ForeignKey for customer
3. ManyToMany to product through OrderProduct

Then, I added the following in admin.py:

```py
# admin.py
...
class OrderInlines(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OrderProduct
    fk_name = "order"
    extra = 1

@admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('order_number', "customer",)
    inlines = (OrderInlines,)
```

Comment: If you have a many-to-many on OrderProduct in Order, then why do you need a Foreign key on OrderProduct for order? Thanks